# Python for loop: continue to next iteration if condition is met

Tags: python, excel, continue

I have a for loop that loops through a list and if `Company = 'XXX'` I would like to skip that iteration. I am using the following but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
for x in line:
    if newCompany=='XXX':
        continue

    else:
        lineToWrite += newCompany+"\t"
```

Really appreciate the help!

Comment: Why do you think it's not working? have you _verified_ (not just assumed) that `newCompany` is `"XXX"` and yet the continue doesn't work? Are you _certain_ line doesn't contain a newline, carriage return, or other invisible characters?

Comment: I think we need to see some more of your code to help.

Comment: You iterates by 

    _x in lines_

but in the if statement you compares _newCompany=='XXX'_. Do you see what could be wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Well it's not very well described but with this information I assume that you are trying to edit those lines that are not 'XXX'.

If it is the case, then I think you are getting it wrong. Instead of checking whether the company is equals to 'XXX' why don't you try to check if it is not:

favorite

I have a for loop that loops through a list and if Company = 'XXX' I would like to skip that iteration. I am using the following but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
for x in line:
    if newCompany !='XXX':
        lineToWrite += newCompany+"\t"
```

But still it doesn't make much sense to me